# Can I combine TPT and TPC inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a dependency to several external suppliers of Data.  Each supplier have very different data model. I map this to an internal data structure.

For simplicty Lets call the data from Supplier for **Item**

So I have a Item table which is the base table for my TPT

Basicly it only Holds the `Id` and the `Name`

I then have Sub tables that "derive" from the Item table

This works nice with **TPT**, but for some of the suppliers one sub table is not enough. I want to use **TPC** for these sub tables otherwise there will be so many joins etc.

Configs looks like this, given name of example data supplier is **Foo**

```
public class ItemConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemConfig()
    {
        HasKey(k => k.Id);
        ToTable("Item");
    }
}

public class FooItemConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<FooItem>
{
    public FooItemConfig()
    {
        Property(cst => cst.Code) //External Identifier for supplier Foo
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        //Because of TPC this config does not map to a table
    }
}

public class ConcreteFooItemConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ConcreteFooItem>
{
    public ConcreteFooItemConfig()
    {
        Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());

        ToTable("ConcreteFooItem");
    }
}
```

Looks pretty straight forward, but I get

> Additional information: The type 'ConcreteFooItem' cannot be mapped as defined
>   because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity
>   splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different
>   inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or
>   change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to
>   not use splitting.

**edit:** I can change **FooItem** to an interface **IFooItem** and that will work,but its not really an option because I want to be able to do queries on **FooItem** level from domain logic that is specific for **FooItem**